# Apache Flink States in ProcessWindowFunction

Tags: apache-flink

I try to understand the difference of various states that can be used in ProcessWindowFunction.

First, ProcessWindowFunction is an AbstractRichFunction

```
abstract class ProcessWindowFunction[IN, OUT, KEY, W <: Window]
    extends AbstractRichFunction {...}
```

As such it can use the method

```
public RuntimeContext getRuntimeContext()
```

to get a state

```
getRuntimeContext().getState
```

Morevoer, process function of WindowProcessFunction

```
def process(key: KEY, context: Context, elements: Iterable[IN], out: 
    Collector[OUT]) {}
```

has a context from where again two methods allow me to get states:

```
/**
  * State accessor for per-key and per-window state.
  */
def windowState: KeyedStateStore

/**
  * State accessor for per-key global state.
  */
def globalState: KeyedStateStore
```

Here my questions:

1) How are these related to getRuntimeContext().getState?

2) I often use a custom Trigger implementation and a GlobalWindow. In this case the state is retrieved with getPartitionedState. Can I access a window state defined in the WindowProcessFunction also in the trigger function? If so how?

3) There is no open method in the Trigger class to override, how is the state creation handled? Is it safe to just call getPartitionedState, which also manages state creation?

Answer (score 5):

1. List item `getRuntimeContext().getState` calls are equivalent to `globalState` of a `ProcessWindowFunction.Context`. Both are "global" states, opposed to "window" states of `windowState`. "global" meaning that the state is shared across all of the windows having the same key. `windowState` is separate per each window, even for the same key. Keep in mind that even "global" state is NOT shared across different keys.
2. It seems to me that `TriggerContext#getPartitionedState()` and `ProcessWindowFunction.Context#globalState()` are pointing to the same thing.
3. Basing on code and one example that I found (`org.apache.flink.table.runtime.triggers.StateCleaningCountTrigger`): yes, `getPartitionedState()` should handle creation of a state if it wasn't created before.